# Searchkick AWS Credentials Expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, searchkick, aws-sdk-ruby

I've set up by `elasticsearch.rb` initializer with the following aws_credentials.

```
  Searchkick.aws_credentials = {
    credentials: Aws::InstanceProfileCredentials.new.credentials,
    region: 'us-west-2',
  }
```

This works fine when I first redeploy but after 12 hours, my credentials expire and I end up with a bunch of these errors:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden ([403] {"message":"The security token included in the request is expired"})
```

This makes sense given the expiration on a set of my credentials appears to be 12 hours. `Aws::InstanceProfileCredentials.new.expiration = 2020-02-13 21:36:30 UTC`

Given that I want to continue to rotate credentials, how do I get Searchkick to pull the latest credentials for each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in the entire `Aws::InstanceProfileCredentials` fixed this

```
  Searchkick.aws_credentials = {
    credentials: Aws::InstanceProfileCredentials.new,
    region: 'us-west-2',
  }
```